# Improve css transitions of list of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a simple portfolio page, but I would like the show and hide of the list items to be more smooth much like the isotope and mixitup plugin. I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Marcus_Dev/fr0ue254/1/) and my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="full">
    <div class="team-container">

        <div class="portfolio-nav">

            <ul>
                <li id="all">All</li>
                <li id="item-1">Stay</li>
                <li id="item-2">Play</li>
                <li id="item-3">Dine</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <section class="work">

            <figure class="item-1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Change Me" />

                    <dl>
                        <dt>Hotel Name</dt>
                        <dd>Location</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </figure>

            <figure class="item-3">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Change Me" />

                    <dl>
                        <dt>Hotel Name</dt>
                        <dd>Location</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </figure>

            <figure class="item-3">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Change Me" />

                    <dl>
                        <dt>Hotel Name</dt>
                        <dd>Location</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </figure>

            <figure class="item-2">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Change Me" />

                    <dl>
                        <dt>Hotel Name</dt>
                        <dd>Location</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </figure>

            <figure class="item-3">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Change Me" />

                    <dl>
                        <dt>Hotel Name</dt>
                        <dd>Location</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </figure>

            <figure class="item-2">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Change Me" />

                    <dl>
                        <dt>Hotel Name</dt>
                        <dd>Location</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </figure>

            <figure class="item-3">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Change Me" />

                    <dl>
                        <dt>Hotel Name</dt>
                        <dd>Location</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </figure>

        </section>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var hotels = $('.work figure');
            hotels.removeClass('current').addClass('all');
                        $('#all').css({
                'font-weight': 'bold',
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $(".portfolio-nav ul li").click(function () {
                $(".portfolio-nav ul li").css({
                  'font-weight': 'regular',
                });
                $(this).css({
                        'font-weight': 'bold',
                });
                    var current = "." + $(this).attr('id');
                    hotels.removeClass('not-current');
                    hotels.not(current).addClass('not-current');
                });

            });
});
```

**SCSS**

```
.portfolio-nav {
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 50px 0;
        text-align: center;
        li {
            display: inline;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 10px;
            color: #666;
            transition: 0.3s;
            &:last-child {
                margin-right: 0;
                &:last-child:after {
                    content: '';
                }
            }
            &:after {
                margin-left: 10px;
                content: '/';
                color: #bbb;
            }
            &:hover {
                color: #000;
                &:after{
                    color: #bbb;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.work {
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;

    figure {
        display: inline-block;
        background: none;
        margin: 2%;
        width: 22%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 !important;
        transition: 0.6s;
        a img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        dl {
            opacity: 1;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 2.2;
            background: rgba(68,141,153,0.8);
            color: white;
            transition: 0.3s;
             dt {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 1em;
                margin-bottom: -16px;
            }

            dd {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        }
         &:hover  dl{
                padding-bottom:3px;
                transition:.3s;
            }
    }

}

.current-li {
  color: #000;
}

figure.current {
   display: inline-block;
        background: none;
        margin: 2%;
        width: 22%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 !important;
        transition: 0.6s;
}

figure.not-current {
   animation-name: test;
   animation-duration: .7s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

@keyframes test{
  0% {
     transform: translate(0px)
  }
  99% {
      transform: translate(200px);
      opacity: 0;
      margin: 2%;
      width: 22%;
  }
  100% {
      margin: 0;
      width: 0;
      opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes go-away{
  50% {
      transform:translateX(100px);
  }
  99% {
      transform:translateX(105px);
      opacity: 0;
  }   
  100% {
      height:0px !important;
      width:0px !important;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Define *"more smooth"*.

Comment: I wanted the positions of the list items to glide into place much like the mixitup plugin https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/

Comment: why don't you use "mixitup"?

Comment: I would rather not use a plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```css
}
.work {
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;

    figure {
        display: inline-block;
        background: none;
        margin: 2%;
        width: 22%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 !important;
        transition: all 0.6s linear;
        a img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        dl {
            opacity: 1;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 2.2;
            background: rgba(68,141,153,0.8);
            color: white;
            transition: 0.3s;
             dt {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 1em;
                margin-bottom: -16px;
            }

            dd {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        }
         &:hover  dl{
                padding-bottom:3px;
                transition:.3s;
            }
    }
    
}

.current-li {
  color: #000;
}

figure.current {
   display: inline-block;
        background: none;
        margin: 2%;
        width: 22%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 !important;
        transition: 0.6s;
}

figure.not-current {
   animation-name: test;
   animation-duration: .7s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

@keyframes test{
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 20%;
    transform: translateX(-200px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 20%;
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 0;
      width: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes go-away{
  50% {
      transform:translateX(100px);
  }
  99% {
      transform:translateX(105px);
      opacity: 0;
  }   
  100% {
      height:0px !important;
      width:0px !important;
  }    
}
```